# How to loop with random.choice and alternation?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a random name generator where the length of the name is 8 characters long. I want it to alternate between 1-2 vowels and then 1-2 consonants until it reaches the 8 character length.

Answer found, messed up the update to the code on here so i had to delete it, but the checkmark is the right way.

Comment: "Nothing happens" because it goes only once into `if`, does the thing, and then leaves it. And then the script ends. (You never enter `else`, so you don't print anything)

Comment: And you are gonna need a loop for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `while` loop instead `if` statement.

```
import random

vowels=('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y')
consonants=('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p',
            'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z')


full_name = random.choice(vowels) + random.choice(consonants)

while len(full_name) < 8:
    full_name += random.choice(vowels) + random.choice(consonants)
else:
    print(full_name)
```